# Rename to Start Case or Initial Caps in Bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, filenames

I need a oneliner to rename all files in a directory from

```
SomeThing.TXT
NOT A FILE.ogg
sensitive lalala.doc
```

to

```
Something.txt
Not A File.ogg
Sensitive Lalala.doc
```

In other words: first letters of words are capital case and everything else is lowercase. This is called [Start case or initial caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Case_styles). It is very close to "Title case". The file extension should be lower case.

Most existing questions seem to only deal with **UPPERCASE.MKV** or **lowercase.mkv** filenames, none seem to cover **Capitalized Case.mkv** ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253584/)).

All the common tools like pipes, `sed`, `perl`, `grep` and more can be used.

Comment: Which Linux are you using? Is it Debian-based?

Comment: @terdon Arch Linux but let's keep it portable enough for that not to matter. :)

Comment: Just wondering what your `rename` is. Is it the perl one on Arch or the BSD one?

Comment: The owning package for `/usr/bin/rename` is `util-linux`. `perl-rename` is a separate command with a [package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/perl-rename/) of the same name.

Comment: Yeah, many systems ship with the util-linux one as default. Well, if you have `perl-rename`, you can use my answer. On my Debian, it claims to warn before overwriting but doesn't actually do so. I also added a shell version that can avoid overwriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a quick solution in one-liner form:

```
for f in *; do mv -i "$f" "`echo $f | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' -e 's/\( .\)/\U\1/g' -e 's/\(^.\)/\U\1/g'`"; done
```

Or in readable (but marginally less comfortable to copy paste form):

```
for f in *; do 
    mv -i "$f" "`echo $f | 
     sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' -e 's/\( .\)/\U\1/g' -e 's/\(^.\)/\U\1/g'`"; 
done
```

This command uses `sed` to `mv` each file to a file with the same name but in which all characters are first [turned to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569825/sed-one-liner-to-convert-all-uppercase-to-lowercase), then each combination of space followed by any character is turned to uppercase, then the first character is turned uppercase.

This will ask before overwriting.

Remove `-i` if you want it automatically to overwrite.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to perl rename, (installed by default as `rename` on Debian-based systems, available as `perl-rename` on many others), you could run:

```
rename  's/.*/lc($&)/e; s/(^| )./uc($&)/ge' *
```

#### Explanation:

The `rename` program will run a perl expression on each of its input file names. Here, the first substitution operation (`s///`) will replace everything (`.*`) with itself (`$&` is whatever was matched) but lower cased (`lc($&)`). The second, will match every character that's after a space or at the beginning of the file name (`(^| )`) and replace it with its upper cased version (`uc($&)`).

Run with the `-n` flag to test without making any changes:

```
$ rename -n 's/.*/lc($&)/e; s/ ./uc($&)/ge' *
rename NOT A FILE.ogg not A File.ogg
rename sensitive lalala.doc sensitive Lalala.doc
rename SomeThing.TXT something.txt
```

---

You could also use a shell loop and perl:

```
for f in *; do 
    mv "$f" "$(perl -lpe 's/.*/lc($&)/e; s/(^| )./uc($&)/ge' <<<"$f")"
done
```

This is the same command as in the `rename` above, only we feed it each file in the directory and use [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to rename.

You could easily modify this to avoid overwriting existing files:

```
for f in *; do 
    target="$(perl -lpe 's/.*/lc($&)/e; s/(^| )./uc($&)/ge' <<<"$f")"; 
    [ -e "$target" ] && 
        echo "File \"$target\" exists, skipping \"$f\"" || 
        mv "$f" "$target"; 
done
```

Comment: The last script works really fine. Unfortunately  on Ubuntu (LTS  14.04.4 LT) the first line proposed generates errors with name with spaces... (`/usr/bin/rename` symlink to `/etc/alternatives/rename` symlink to `/usr/bin/prename` ;  perl file RCSfile: rename,v   Revision: 4.1 ).

Answer (score 1):

"De-capitalizing" answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581564/3637404):

```
for i in *
do
  mv "$i" "$( echo $i | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"
done
```

Capitalizing already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803627/3637404):

```
for i in *
do
  mv "$i" "$( echo $i | sed 's/[ ]*/\u&/g')"
done
```

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Even if the link is pointing to other sites on the SE network. Instead, copy the relevant information into your question or write an answer to _this_ question, based on the information there.

Comment: Please summarize the linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works on `Bash 3.2.57` for Mac OSX

Preview (doesn't change anything):

```
IFS=$'\n';FOLDER=new;for F in $(ls -1);do EXT="${F##*.}";NAME="${F%.*}";NEW=$(echo "$NAME"| perl -pe 's/[ _-]([A-z0-9])([^ _-]+)/ \U\1\L\2/g');echo "cp '$F' '$FOLDER/$NEW.$EXT'";done
```

If the preview looks good, you can use this to rename and cp into subfolder:

```
IFS=$'\n';FOLDER=new;[ -d $FOLDER ] || mkdir $FOLDER;for F in $(ls -1);do EXT="${F##*.}";NAME="${F%.*}";NEW=$(echo "$NAME"| perl -pe 's/[ _-]([A-z0-9])([^ _-]+)/ \U\1\L\2/g');cp -v "$F" "$FOLDER/$NEW.$EXT";done
```

Notes:

- Will not change the file extension.
- Should handle numbers correctly.
- If you have other chars you want to be converted to spaces, just add them to the character class: `[ _-]`
- Avoids conflicting names by making a **copy** of each file into a subfolder. This gives you an "undo" option.  Another way to handle this would be to rename all files, while adding a prefix like `_My New File Name.jpg`, then rename all of those to versions without the `_`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to rename the first character of a file name.